# What applications of clients use bitcoin JSON-RPC?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

As far as I understood, the [`Bitcoin JSON-RPC`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)) is one of the ways (if not the [only way](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22031/for-application-development-is-bitcoind-rpc-the-only-way)) in which applications can be built that can access the bitcoin wallet. So, the RPC server here gives that access and any client (or app) can access via APIs.

So far, I have just figured our that only `bitcoin-cli` is such a local application which uses the RPC. Are there any other examples where the JSON-RPC is used?

In other words, are there any Desktop apps (mainly) that can access the bitcoin wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understood, the Bitcoin JSON-RPC is one of the ways (if
>   not the only way) in which applications can be built that can access
>   the bitcoin wallet.

There is also a [REST interface](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md), but that is for read-only type commands like getting blocks or transaction info.

> So far, I have just figured our that only bitcoin-cli is such a local
>   application which uses the RPC.

`bitcoin-cli` is just a cli interface to the RPC, it doesn't really do anything on it's own. Also, the `RPC` interface isn't just for wallet commands. A list of commands can be found in the documentation at https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.2/. The commands expose functionality including:

- blockchain
- control
- generating
- mining
- network
- rawtransactions
- util
- wallet

> Are there any other examples where the JSON-RPC is used?

Many software libraries will communicate with the Bitcoin Core `RPC`, too many to list, but this might be a good start: https://github.com/igorbarinov/awesome-bitcoin. Not all use the Bitcoin core RPC, some implement their own full node (like copay).